# Mysql: Select only ip addresses from mixed column. Is there a function that I can use?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a column in mysql with a mix of IP addresses and email addresses.  Is there a MySQL function that can identify a string as an ip address?

If not, what other methods would you recommend?

Regards

J

Comment: use `REGEX` in mysql or you can provide sample value so that we can write it for you

Comment: Have a look at [`inet-aton`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton) returns numeric for an ip and returns null for email [`Demo`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/52511)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use REGEXP in mysql query

so to select only ip addresses from column you can write

select * from tableName where columnname REGEXP '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$';

example

```
select * from value1 where newValue REGEXP '^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+$';
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LOCATE function. This SELECT will bring everything that doesn't have an @.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOCATE ('@', field)=0;
```

Answer (score -1):

As emails have to contain a "@" and IPs can't, you could select them like this:

```
select c from t where c not like '%@%';
```

Comment: anybody bother to tell me why they don't like "like"?